# How to troubleshoot Busy (Waiting for role to start...) when RDP is unresponsive?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role that I'm trying to scale the instances.  When I increase the instances from 1 to 2 I can see it creates the VM and calls OnRoleStart.  It never gets past OnRoleStart and the server does not respond to RDP requests.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using [Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433048.aspx) which you pump logging details to.  This way you can see what, if anything is going on on the host.